# What is Srikantha's Visisthadvait Philosophy?

Tags: shiva, philosophy, vedanta, shaivism, srikanthacharya

Does any one know what Siva Visishtadvaita (Shrouta Shaiva Siddhanta) philosophy by Srikantha Acharya is all about?

I know what is advaita philosophies but not this one.

Answer (score 2):

Śrīkaṇṭha's Vishishtadvaita darsana is like Ramanuja's system except that in this system Siva and not Narayana is the Supreme.

> Śrīkaṇṭha is one of the important ācāryas who have written
> commentaries on the Brahmasūtras. He advocates a type of Śaivism as
> contained in the Vāyavīya-saṁhitā of the Śivapurāṇa.
>
> According to him Brahman is Śiva (Saguṇa-Brahman). Prakṛti (nature)
> and jīvas (individual souls who are atomic in size) are his parts as
> it were. Evolution of the world takes place as per his will and
> supervision. Though, thus, he is the nimittakāraṇa or the efficient
> cause, he is, in a way, the upādānakāraṇa or the material cause also
> since prakṛti is his part.
>
> Śrīkaṇṭha considers that the performance of Vedic sacrifices and the
> prescribed duties without any selfish motive, prepares a person for
> the realisation of Śiva.
>
> Man (or the soul) is free to do good or bad as per his saṁskāras
> carried over from the previous lives. However, Śiva the merciful, is
> ever eager to help him to do good and get liberation.
>
> The souls are the conscious knowers, both by way of the senses and by
> the manas (superior mind, which is a special property possessed by
> them, different from the ordinary mind which is a product of prakṛti).
> By following the path of jñānayoga, the threefold impurities of the
> mind (See MALA for details.) are removed and self-knowledge is fully
> manifested. It is almost like the knowledge of Brahman.
>
> In the state of liberation, the soul has no body but enjoys bliss
> through the mind. If it wants, it can also create its own body and
> enjoy all happiness. It is never again brought under the control of
> karma.
>
> Śrīkaṇṭha’s philosophy may be termed as Śivaviśiṣṭādvaita, because of
> its similarity to Rāmānuja’s system.
>
> Appayya Dīkṣita (A. D. 1520-1592) has written an excellent commentary
> called Śivārkamaṇidīpikā on the bhāṣya of Śrīkaṇṭha.
>
> It is not known when exactly Śrīkaṇṭha lived. Some scholars suggest
> that he lived in A. D. 1270 and was from Andhra Pradesh.

**A Concise Encyclopedia of Hinduism by Swami Harshananda**